# How to change Java Version for Apache Tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu-18.04

So I'm running apache tomcat 9, when I check the `/manager` page it shows the jvm version as `11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1`.

I want to use Java version 8, how would I change this?

I have read around online and could not find anything that works.

OS: ubuntu 18.04

It's not a duplicate because I have read that post already and I found the answers unhelpful / not working. (Also that thread is targeted toward the windows OS as I'm based on Ubuntu (CLI only).)

Comment: @jhamon no, I tried the solutions but they did not work / did not provide a well enough explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing so.

1. Chaining global `JAVA_HOME` environment variables to the java you wish to use. Note that this will change Java for all apps running on that machine.
2. Using setenv file. In `CATALINA_BASE/bin` directory open or create file named `setenv.sh` and put `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8-jdk` in it. This will change it only for your tomcat. Please note to change it to the JDK/JRE you want to use.

Comment: Is the CATALINA_BASE directory essentially my tomcat directory?

Comment: @user12346306 yes

Comment: Alright great, I am doing it now, should I restart tomcat to initiate this?

Comment: @user12346306 yes, restart it

Comment: It seems tomcat9 may not read /etc/environment. See this bug report: https://github.com/cuba-platform/documentation/issues/659 So, it can be set at  /etc/default/tomcat9 or by using another method.

Comment: I have to create `setenv.sh` in `bin` directory of `CATALINA_HOME` which is `/usr/share/tomcat9`

Answer (score 1):

**Using the "setenv" script (optional, recommended)**

Apart from CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE, all environment variables can
be specified in the "setenv" script. The script is placed either into
CATALINA_BASE/bin or into CATALINA_HOME/bin directory and is named
setenv.bat (on Windows) or setenv.sh (on *nix). The file has to be
readable.

By default the setenv script file is absent. If the script file is present
both in CATALINA_BASE and in CATALINA_HOME, the one in CATALINA_BASE is
preferred.

For example, to configure the JRE_HOME and CATALINA_PID variables you can
create the following script file:

On *nix, $CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh:

JRE_HOME=/usr/java/latest
CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_BASE/tomcat.pid"

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/RUNNING.txt